k) portion of parse tree of user defined function
In the below, why does the eval fail but the value works?
Also, what exactly is the k){x'y} part of the parse output and why did I have to enclose it in quotes for the value statement to work?
q)colist: `a`b`c

q){(=;x;0)} each colist
= `a 0
= `b 0
= `c 0

q)parse "{(=;x;0)} each colist"
k){x'y}
{(=;x;0)}
`colist

q)eval ("k){x'y}"; {(=;x;0)}; colist)
'c
  [0]  eval ("k){x'y}"; {(=;x;0)}; colist)
       ^

q)value ("k){x'y}"; {(=;x;0)}; colist)
= `a 0
= `b 0
= `c 0




There's a few things here:

eval evaluates a parse tree, value (in this context) is building the parse tree. So they would not be expected the behave the same.
k){x'y} is the result of parsing each

q)each
k){x'y}

More specifically it is the underlying k code. If you don't like it, replace it with the q equivalent, e.g.
q)eval(each;{(=;x;0)};`colist)
= `a 0
= `b 0
= `c 0

or combine the function-each into one
q)eval({(=;x;0)}each;`colist)
= `a 0
= `b 0
= `c 0


The value-of-string approach worked because value supports supplying functionality within a string

q)value("{x+1}";4)
5

whereas eval would interpret this as indexing the string at index 4
q)eval("{x+1}";4)
"}"

